# Usage of the word concurrence

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

Is it correct to ask "Are we all in concurrence?" synonymously to "Are we all in agreement?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Are we all in concurrence?" is not incorrect, but unnecessarily wordy.  I would suggest your synonym is better, but if the word "concur" is closer to your intended meaning, I would say "Do we concur?"

An important point to note is that "concurrence" implies "all" anyway, so leave "all" off.

Comment: Yes, the _all_ is unnecessary. The metaphor -- and it's an old one, dating back to Latin -- is that we are all running together (_con_ + _current_ 'they run together'), keeping pace, in step, as a group; following the leader. It is a bit wordy, but it has a sense that may be good value for the word.

Answer (score 0):

The words are technically synonymous, but one look at [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=concurrence,agreement&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows just how rare "concurrence" is used.  In fact, the phrase "all in concurrence" reports no NGram findings whatsoever.

So, yes, you can say it's "correct", but you can probably expect to get some odd looks or even confusion if you try to use it.